# How to checkout a specific tag before running the Pipeline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline

I am trying out AWS CodePipeline and currently have it hooked up to our Github account where it can checkout the `master` branch no issues, as this is set in the Source settings.

However, this is obviously quite restrictive, and I'd like to be able to specific a version tag from Github to checkout, but canot see anyway of achieveing this?

Ideally, I want to specify a version number (tag in Github) before the Pipeline runs, so I can use 1 Pipeling to checkout, build, test, deploy the codebase for a specific version tag. Again, I cannot find any information on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

This is not natively supported at the moment.

But you could configure your CodePipeline to create a Full Git Clone instead of just an artifact, and then pass that to a CodeBuild where you can use git to checkout the specific tag as outlined in the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/tutorials-github-gitclone.html).

Comment: is this still not supported?